# Does gzread modify the input buf value?

Tags: c, gzip, zlib

I'm reading the [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip), and am wondering about the gzread function:

`ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzread OF((gzFile file, voidp buf, unsigned len));`

This gives the number of uncompressed bytes, but does anything else come of this function?  I'm skeptical this is the case (because not a pointer is passed to the function it seems, `voidp buf`), but does gzread also "read" the data into `voidp buf`?

Is there an analogue to gzread in the standard library (like gzopen ~ fopen)?

I'm reading a project called [klib](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), and in one of the files (kseq.h, line 91), gzread is called (there it will be called `__read`, but I am reading another project, [hickit](https://github.com/lh3/hickit), which calls it as `gzread`), and wondering if gzread modifies the buf value or not.

Comment: "but does gzread also "read" the data into voidp buf". Yes, clearly it does. What else would the `bufp` arg be there for? The manual is not super explicit but it's clear that "Reads the given number of uncompressed bytes from the compressed file" means read into `bufp`.

Comment: To be clear : `gzread` reads data from gzFile, uncompresses it, writes it into the memory pointed by `bufp` and returns the number of bytes written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, up to `len` bytes are written to `buf`.

Comment: I will update the zlib documentation to be crystal clear in this regard.